# The given id must not be null with Spring Data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm developing an application written in `Spring Framework 5`, I'm also using `Spring Data` to access the `PostgreSQL` database, and I have a strange problem which occurs sometimes when I'm querying the database.

In short, I have a service which contains `myMainFunction`. That function is called from the controller, and that function calls `myFunction` which calculates and sets the ID to the object. `myFunction` then also queries the database to find if the object with calculated ID already exists in the database.

Then `myMainFunction` again quires the database to get the object with the same ID, if it exists. This is the line where `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!` is sometimes thrown.

I can't understand why is this happening, and why is that happening sometimes, not all the time?

This is the "pseudo-code" which causes the problem:

```
publi class MyService {
    ...

    public myMainFunction(MyObject object) {
        ...
        myFunction(object);
        Optional<MyObject> oldObject = objectRepository.findById(object.getId());
        ...
    }


    private void myFunction(MyObject object) {
        ...
        object.setId(calculateId(...));
        Optional<MyObject> existingObject = objectRepository.findById(object.getId());
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Are you sure error comes from `spring`!!! and doesn't come from `calculateId(...)`?

Comment: Why don't you use auto generated IDs? Is there any technical reason?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, please.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that error doesn't come from caclulateId function. I don't use auto generated ID-s because ID of the every object depends on some business case and needs some particular format.

Comment: Are you sure that `calculateId` method always returns `not-null` value? Put logging between calculating and querying and try to check logs in that case when error appears.

Comment: I'm sure, but I will add that log.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I completely forgot that caculateId() method depends on the external system on which it queries some data which is then used to create the ID for the object. It turned out that sometimes it is possible that that external system has all the data but no the one necessary for the ID creation, and that the caculateId() throws the business exception which I then silently swallowed in myMainFunction becaouse I didn't properly handle it. So the ID was null when the repository method was called.